# How can I expand masked intervals in a timeseries dataframe to adjacent rows?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a timeseries dataset that has intervals of bad measurements. I clean the data by using `df.mask()` to reject the bad measurements that are above or below a threshold. However, I'm concerned that part of the adjacent intervals are impacted by bad measurements as well, but not enough to exceed the threshold. To be safe, I'd like to also mask these adjacent intervals as well.

For example:

```py
>>> df
   seconds  value
0        1      5
1        2      2
2        3     -1
3        4     -3
4        5      2
5        6      4
6        7      6

>>> # Mask the negative values because we know those are bad measurements
>>> df["good value"] = df["value"].mask(lambda x: x < 0)

>>> df 
   seconds  value  good value
0        1      5         5.0
1        2      2         2.0    # <--- want to mask as well
2        3     -1         NaN
3        4     -3         NaN
4        5      2         2.0    # <--- want to mask as well
5        6      4         4.0
6        7      6         6.0
```

How can I expand any blocks of masked values into one or two adjacent rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can shift the mask to adjacent rows

```py
df["good value"] = df["value"].mask(df["value"].lt(0) | df["value"].lt(0).shift(-1) | df["value"].lt(0).shift())
```

```
print(df)

   seconds  value  good value
0        1      5         5.0
1        2      2         NaN
2        3     -1         NaN
3        4     -3         NaN
4        5      2         NaN
5        6      4         4.0
6        7      6         6.0
```